# Modelling dice rolls in F#

Tags: f#

I am doing some Monte Carlo simulations on dice rolls using F# and I am using integers to represent a single roll of a dice and a list of integers to represent a list of dice rolls.  I would like to be able to model the dice roll instead of integers as a type.  I am only using 6 sided dice and I would like a type that has some of the characteristics of a Alias / Synonym type and some of the properties of either a Discriminated Union or a Enum.

These are what I would like to see on my type

1. I would like the type to behave like an integer so I can max / min / sum / fold on the lists.
2. I would like the type to be able to be assigned as an integer value.
3. I would like the type to be constrained to 1-6 so that there can be no dice roll of a zero and no dice roll of a seven.

I have tried the combination of types listed above and all seem to have some draw backs (which might be my usage and understanding rather than the Types themselves).

This is just a trivial example of something I am doing for fun (not profit) but would like to see an answer as I could imagine using this in more serious data modelling.

Comment: Just curious: are you 'pondering' dice rolls? :)

Comment: The usual way to do this is to create a type without exporting its constructors, then create a function `int -> DiceRoll option` which returns nothing if the argument is out of range. You can then create a function `DiceRoll -> int` to extract the value and add any operators you want to support.

Comment: I am taking part in the MOOC https://www.edx.org/course/mitx/mitx-11-126x-introduction-game-design-2881 and I am playing around with dice calculation rules that create interesting probability distributions but that are difficult for players to reason about (as opposed to simply rolling 2 dice).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like a Discriminated Union with some static methods can handle everything you want

```
open System

type D6 = 
    | One | Two | Three | Four | Five | Six

    member self.Value =
        match self with
        | One  -> 1      | Two  -> 2      | Three -> 3
        | Four -> 4      | Five -> 5      | Six   -> 6

    override self.ToString() =
        match self with
        | One  -> "One"  | Two  -> "Two"  | Three -> "Three"
        | Four -> "Four" | Five -> "Five" | Six   -> "Six"

    static member Create (num:int) =
        match num with
        | 1    -> One    | 2    -> Two    | 3     -> Three   
        | 4    -> Four   | 5    -> Five   | 6     -> Six     
        | _    -> failwithf "Could not create D6, %d is not in range 1-6" num

    static member inline Roll() = Random().Next(1,7) |> D6.Create
```

Calling D6.Roll() will generate single random roll

`> D6.Roll();;  val it : D6 = Four`

`> D6.Roll();;  val it : D6 = Six`

`> D6.Roll();;  val it : D6 = Two`

`> D6.Roll();;  val it : D6 = Five`

You can create static members and operators that make it easy to compose your D6s together

```
    static member inline Add      (a:D6) (b:D6) = a.Value + b.Value
    static member inline (+)      (a    , b   ) = D6.Add a b
    static member inline Subtract (a:D6) (b:D6) = a.Value - b.Value
    static member inline (-)      (a    , b   ) = D6.Subtract a b
```

And static members that make it easy to create them from a list of input

```
    static member FromList (numls: int list ) =
        numls |> List.map D6.Create
```

Comparison works out the box with this type

`D6.One > D6.Two;;
   val it : bool = false`

`D6.One < D6.Two;;
   val it : bool = true`

Infinite sequences make it easy to generate randomized input

```
let rollGen =
    let rnd = Random()
    let rec gen() = seq {   yield rnd.Next(1,7) 
                            yield! gen()        }
    gen()
```

`> rollGen;; 
    val rollGen : seq<int>`

Which can be mapped over to create an infinite random sequence of D6

```
let d6Gen = rollGen |> Seq.map D6.Create
```

`> d6Gen;;
    val d6Gen : seq<D6>`

If you want to pull a static list of input values that you can reuse out of the random infinite sequence you need to use functions like

```
let rollList num = rollGen |> Seq.take num |> List.ofSeq

let d6List   num = d6Gen   |> Seq.take num |> List.ofSeq ;;
```

`let _20rolls = rollList 20 ;;`

`> val _20rolls : int list =
   [3; 4; 2; 3; 5; 6; 4; 6; 6; 6; 5; 3; 4; 3; 2; 1; 2; 5; 3; 6]*)`

`let _30d6 = d6List 30 ;;`

`> val _30d6 : D6 list =
   [Two; Six; One; Three; Two; Three; One; One; Six; Six; Four; Four; Three;
    Four; One; Five; Three; Four; Four; Four; Three; Two; Six; Four; One; Three;
    One; Five; Two; Two]`

[Gist of just the code](https://gist.github.com/cloudRoutine/e041b62fe120cf656a59)

Comment: That looks really useful, I will try playing with this later

Answer (score 4):

As one of the options you could create your own numeric type as described in this post by Tomas Petricek:
http://tomasp.net/blog/fsharp-custom-numeric.aspx/index.html